# Download a project from a Github page

Tags: github

I need to download the following Visual Studio demo example from Github:

https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/ApplicationFundamentals/ServiceSamples/BoundServiceDemo

But in my browser, no options for downloading the folder as a zip file are shown.

Is there any simple way to download this VS project as a zip file?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download it as a zip file from [here](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples).

You just need to click on the `Code` button and download the zip file.

Click on `Download zip` in here.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to go to the root of the repository located [here](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples).

From there, click the green `code` button and there's an option to download a ZIP of the entire repository. Then just take the bits you want/need.

[image]

Comment: That link contains a lot of projects. Seems there si no way to download the specific project.